# Getting an out of bounds error on my macro

Tags: excel, vba

I was making a VBA script which pulls an excel sheet from a page, copies it into my current page, then applies a recorded macro which changes the table filters. The issue occurs in the filters, where I am getting an out of range error every other time I run the script.

My guess is that it occurs since the item is already set under a certain filter, that if I rerun the macro, it doesn't know how to deal with that situation.

I was curious if anyone could find a fix to this.

```
Sub FilterCES()

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Stories").Range.AutoFilter Field:=27, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(0, "6/3/2019")

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Stories").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1 _
    :="Released to Customers"
'Filer by Type:
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Stories").Range.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1 _
    :=Array("full_trial", "renewal", "sale", "trial_to_sale"), Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Stories").Range.AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1 _
    :=Array("academic", "public_library", "schools"), 
    Operator:=xlFilterValues

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Stories").Range.AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1 _
    :=Array("Australia", "Canada", "Finland", "Germany", "Italy", 
"Netherlands", _
    "New Zealand", "United Kingdom (GB)", "United States", "Nordics", 
"Norway", "Sweden", "Finland", "Denmark"), Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

I expected the macro to just change the settings to whatever I had selected since it uses auto filtering, but that isn't the case and I get an out of range error.

Comment: What line does the error occur on? And what error is it exactly? Error 440 “Array Index out of Bounds”?

Comment: It occurs on the first filter, so    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Stories").Range.AutoFilter Field:=27, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(0, "6/3/2019")

Comment: Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Answer (score 1):

Could you try insering this line between each filtering?

Activesheet.AutoFilterMode = False

just like this:

```
Activesheet.AutoFilterMode = False
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Stories").Range.AutoFilter Field:=27, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(0, "6/3/2019")


Acivesheet.AutoFilterMode = False
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Stories").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1 _
    :="Released to Customers"
.......
```

Comment: I tried it out, but that didn't seem to be the problem. thank you anyways.